# Vorticity on a Lie group

Tags: lie-groups

Let $M:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathfrak{sl}(2;R)$ be differentiable, and define the 1-form $\rho=\frac{1}{2}(M^{-1}dM-dM M^{-1})$,
where $$M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{pmatrix}$$ 
The structure equation $d\rho+[\rho,\rho]=0$ is verified whenever we have $a db\wedge dc+b dc\wedge da+ cda\wedge db=0$. This holds e.g. when M is symmetric, and allows to define the "logarithm of M" as the "primitive" of $\rho$ in $\mathrm{SL}(2;R)$ or rather, its covering. 
Similar things hold for hermitian traceless 2x2 matrices. Can this definition extend to more general Lie groups, as the symplectic group? And what could it be good for?